# Django: User Login only working with terminal created users

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

I'm only new to django & this is my first time posting on stack overflow so appologies if I havent done this right.

My problem is that when I use my login function, it only seems to work with those created with the createsuperuser command in the terminal. Those created within the website just dont work.
The users show within the admin panel and have a password within them.

models.py

```
class Trickster_User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

  UserID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  Email = models.EmailField(('Email Address'), unique=True)
  Username = models.CharField(('Username'),max_length=25, unique=True)
  FirstName = models.CharField(('First Name'),max_length=25)
  LastName = models.CharField(('Last Name'),max_length=25)
  is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

  objects = CustomUserManager()

  USERNAME_FIELD = 'Email'
  REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['Username', 'FirstName', 'LastName']

  def __str__(self):
      return self.FirstName + ' ' + self.LastName
```

views.py

```
def user_login(request):
  context = {}
  user = request.user
  if user.is_authenticated:
    return redirect('home')

  if request.method == "POST":
    form = UserAuthenticationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
      Email = request.POST['Email']
      password = request.POST['password']
      user = authenticate(Email=Email, password=password)

      if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        return redirect('home')
        
  else:
    form = UserAuthenticationForm()

  context['user_login'] = form
  return render(request, 'authentication/login.html', context)
```

forms.py

```
class UserAuthenticationForm(forms.ModelForm):

  Email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
  password = forms.CharField(label='password', widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))

  class Meta:
    model = Trickster_User
    fields = ('Email', 'password')

  def clean(self):
    Email = self.cleaned_data['Email']
    password = self.cleaned_data['password']
    if not authenticate(Email=Email, password=password):
      raise forms.ValidationError("Invalid Login")
```

login.html

```
{% block content  %}
  <div class="shadow  p-4 mb-5 bg-body rounded">

    <h1> Login </h1>
    <br/><br/>

    <form action="" method=POST enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
      {% csrf_token %}
      {% for feild in user_login %}
        <p>
          {{ feild.label_tag }}
          {{ feild}}

          {% if feild.help_text %}
            <small style="color: grey">{{ feild.help_text }}</small>
          {% endif %}

          {% for errors in field.errors %}
            <p style="color: red">{{ feild.errors }}</p>
          {% endfor %}

          {% if user_login.non_feild_errors %}
            <div style="color:red";>
              <p>{{ user_login.non_feild_errors }}</p>
            </div>
          {% endif %}
        </p>
      {% endfor %}
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
    </form>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Code to register users:

views.py

```
   def register_user(request):
    context = {}
    if request.method == "POST":
      form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
      if form.is_valid():
        form.save()

        Email = form.cleaned_data.get('Email')
        raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        user = authenticate(Email=Email, password=raw_password)
        login(request, user)

        messages.success(request, ("Registration Successful! Password"))
        return redirect('home')
      else:
        context['UserRegistrationForm'] = form
    else:
      form = UserRegistrationForm()
      context['UserRegistrationForm'] = form

    return render(request, 'authentication/register_user.html', context)
```

register_user.html

```
    {% block content  %}

{% if form.errors %}
  <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
    There was an error with your form!
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
  </div>
{% endif %}

  <div class="shadow  p-4 mb-5 bg-body rounded">
    <h1> Register </h1>
    <br/><br/>

    <form action="{% url 'register_user' %}" method=POST enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
      {% csrf_token %}
      {% for feild in UserRegistrationForm %}
        <p>
          {{ feild.label_tag }}
          {{ feild}}

          {% if feild.help_text %}
            <small style="color: grey">{{ feild.help_text }}</small>
          {% endif %}

          {% for errors in field.errors %}
            <p style="color: red">{{ feild.errors }}</p>
          {% endfor %}
        </p>
      {% endfor %}
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

    </form>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Ive seen one other post on something simmilar to this but the only solution posted was to change the 'is_active' status to True by default.

I tried this and am still running into same issue.

Comment: Can you add the code where you register the user?

Comment: @vinkomlacic Just added the registration code there now.

Comment: AFAIK, if `is_active` is not set to `True`, the `login()` would fail, that is why `is_active` is created. May this solve your issue

Comment: @whoami is_active is defaulted to True and when I look in the admin pannel it is also True.